# Get latest files with lftp

Tags: ftp, ssl, lftp

I would like to know if it was possible to download all latest files on an ftp server with `lftp` without downloading the older files.

Examples;

On my server I have

```
/doc
/vps
/order/{id}
/order/{id}
/order/archives
```

On my computer:

```
/order/1010
/order/3058
```

If I delete `/order/3058`, the script must not download it again.

I would like to download all `/order/{id}` as they become available. But, these change everyday and I don't want to download all `order/{id}` each time, only the latest.

The particularity is my server is secured with SSL and I need this to connect

```
set ftp:ssl-force true
set ftp:ssl-protect-data true
set ssl:verify-certificate false
```

Answer (score 1):

No, [`lftp`](http://lftp.yar.ru/lftp-man.html) does not do exactly what you are asking.  That would make it necessary for `lftp` to remember the previous updates.  Instead, its `mirror` feature provides these scenarios which rely only upon a comparison of the *current* directory contents:

- download all updates
- download updates, while deleting local files which no longer exist on the remote server.

However (if you maintain a list of local deletions which can be applied to a script), `lftp` has an option for *excluding* files:

> **`-X`** *GP*,   **`--exclude-glob=`** *GP*
>           exclude matching files
>
> Include and exclude options can be specified multiple times. It means that a file  or  directory  would  be  mirrored  if  it matches an include and does not match to excludes after the
>   include, or does not match anything and the first check is exclude. Directories  are  matched with a slash appended.

Using the `-X` option, `lftp` could do what you want, but only with some work on your part.